# Formula to match two values between two worksheets

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets...Days and Visits.  The first spreadsheet `(Days)` contains Name/Date.  The second spreadsheet `(Visits)` also contains Name/Date.  I am trying to get a formula that if the name and date appear on both spreadsheets that a value of "Yes" is returned on the `Visits` spreadsheet.

This is the formula I'm using but the Yes/No column an say "No" but I can clearly see some names should say Yes.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Physician Visits'!$A$2:$F$800,MATCH(1,IF('Physician Visits'!$A$2:$F$800=A2,IF('Physician Visits'!$A$2:$F$800=C2,1)),0)),"No")}
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Are Name/Date two separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way you have written your formula you are trying to find to different values in the same cell.  The two IF's iterate together and since the ranges in the criteria are the same the cell in which you are looking are the same.  And one cell cannot equal two different values at the same time.

There is a better way, use COUNTIFS()

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Physician Visits'!$A:$A,A2,'Physician Visits'!$F:$F,C2),"YES","NO")
```

This assumes your comparing column A to Column A and Column C to Column F.  If different ensure your are comparing the correct columns to one another.

Comment: Worked PERFECT!  THANK YOU!  :)

Comment: @TheWarden If this worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.